# How to construct a table, with the results of an ajax call, with the first cell as an image?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, concatenation, src

I am building a table with the results of an ajax call. The first cell needs to contain an img sourced from the internet.  I have highlighted the relevant section of code between double asterisks:

```
$.ajax({        
       method: "GET", 
       url: "getrecords_ajax.php",
       data:{mypath:mypath},
       }).done(function( data ) { 
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        var string='<table id="mytable">';
 /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */  
        $.each( result, function( key, value ) {
             **string += "<tr><td>" +<img src=`https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/9780974514055- 
             S.jpg` />+"</td><td>"+value['book_id'] +" </td></tr>";       
              }); **
                  string += '</table>';
                  $("#records").html(string); 
       }); 
});
```

What I want the html code to look like is:

```
<td><img src="https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/9780974514055-S.jpg" /></td>
```

I recognise that I need to put the <img src clause in speechmarks, and possibly escape the https clause with backticks but this doesn't work eg

```
<td>" +<img src=`https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/9780974514055-S.jpg` />+ "</td>
```

I have tried 100's of other combinations but with no success.
To make matters worse, if I find the right syntax, then I have to further complicate it by replacing the ="https://covers.openlibrary..." element with a variable (otherwise every row will all have the same image). Phew!!

Comment: I have found that        <td>"+ myimg +" </td>   partially works in that the program continues but it just prints the text eg http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/0547892470-S.jpg   rather than going to the source and collecting the img

Comment: SOLVED - I forgot to add the <img src=